# What is this analog of $\mathbb A^1$ / proper homotopy theory?

Tags: homotopy-theory

In homotopy theory, we can construct the $\infty$-category of spaces from the  ordinary category of oriented manifolds $\rm Man$, by freely co-completing it, imposing gluing relations, and homotopy invariance.  This sort of procedure is described model-categorically by Dugger in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007070.

My question is:  Is it possible to perform an analog of this construction,  where instead of homotopy invariance,  we only impose that $\mathbb R^1$ is invertible?  That is,  we freely make $\mathbb R^1 \times -$ an equivalence.

Is there a source for this sort of localization of multiplication by objects in a symmetric monoidal category? It is analogous to the process of constructing spectra.

If  this sort of localization exists,  what do we get in this case?  I suppose it's possible that we just get the ordinary homotopy category again.  Alternately,  we could get something related to the proper homotopy category.

Comment: Are you considering the real line as a manifold or as a topological space? In the latter case, there's nothing new.

Comment: @user40276 Currently as a manifold.  Do you expect these cases to be different?   This question is for "curiosity only,"  so anything relevant you can say /  pointers you have in the  direction of more info are welcome.

Comment: I think that if you invert the line in the category of $\infty$-sheaves over cartesian spaces (which is equivalent to $\infty$-stacks over manifolds) you will get the category of spaces back (you will get stacks over a point). A more interesting thing would be to invert the circle as a differentiable manifold to get a motivic differentiable theory. But maybe the result will again be trivial. Maybe you're interested in something like the property of exhibiting cohesion as in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos

Comment: @user40276 Could you sketch why its trivial?  E.g. why is $\mathbb R^1$ isomorphic to a point?  Notice  I'm using "localization" in a non-standard way. I'm not sure if cohesion is the concept I want.

Comment: I was assuming that you were using the localisation at ${X \times \mathbf{A}^1 \longrightarrow X}$ of the $\infty$-topos of sheaves over differentiable manifolds. Or equivalently, the Bousfield localisation at the projections on the category of simplicial presheaves with the local model structure. In this case, the localisation will consist in sheaves such that $F (X) \cong F (X \times \mathbf{A}^1)$. However, all cartesian spaces are products of $\mathbf{A}^1$.

Comment: And I was not talking about only cohesion. I was referring to the concept of a line exhibiting cohesion. See also 1.38 and 1.39 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos+--+structures#RealLineIsTheContinuum

Comment: @user40276 OP is asking specifically NOT about localizing at X\times R^1 -> X (which is addressed in the first paragraph of the question) but instead about forcing the object R^1 to become invertible with respect to Cartesian product (formally adding an object R^{-1} to the category). This is possible using a construction in Mario Robalo’s thesis but it’s not a localization, your objects are gonna be some kind of spectra wrt R^1. I don’t think you’d recover any well known construction, it just looks like a weird thing to do

Comment: @Gasterbiter Ah, ok. My bad. I've misunderstood the question. I know a non published (I think) thesis where one can do motivic homotopy theory in an infinity locally presentable cartesian closed category with a circle object (no restrictions on this kind of object). In this setting, it's possible to develop a nice K-theory and Snaith's theorem holds.

Comment: @Gasterbiter  Thanks for the reference--- Marco's thesis has a lot of useful info.   I'd argue that for geometers (who know about things like dimension)  this construction is not so weird.   For instance people often take the grothendieck ring of varieties,  and they invert $\mathbb A^1$-- they don't set it equal to $1$.

Comment: @user1092847 The $\mathbb{A}^1$ that is inverted in the Grothendieck ring of varieties is actually more similar to the Tate motive in $SH$ than to the $\mathbb{A}^1$ in motivic homotopy theory: it's what's left after you "quotient" the point at infinity out of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @DenisNardin  I agree, in fact that's the point of my question.  The usual $\mathbb A^1$ homotopy  is like setting $\mathbb A^1 = 1$,  whereas I'm asking  (for manifolds,  but we might as well do it for schemes too)  what happens when we just invert it.

Comment: @user1092847 Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but my point is that in the analogy you shouldn't expect to invert $\mathbb{A}^1$, but to invert the Tate motive (which is exactly what you do in ordinary motivic homotopy theory). But I have no intuition about what's "supposed" to happen when you invert $\mathbb{A}^1$. You certainly get something, but do you have any application in mind (e.g. a cohomology theory with this property)?

Comment: @DenisNardin It's possible that we think about the Grothendieck ring of varieties in different ways.  For me, the ring is the universal compactly supported Euler characteristic.  The Tate motive is the compactly supported motive of $\mathbb A^1$, which is what we invert.

Comment: @user1092847 Sure, but the analogue of that in motivic homotopy theory is not the sheaf represented by $\mathbb{A}^1$ (that would be the "noncompactly supported motive of $\mathbb{A}^1$", which is contractible), but the sheaf corresponding to the pointed scheme $\mathbb{P}^1$ (pointed at infinity). Think about how to define compactly supported cohomology you take the cohomology of a compactification and quotient out the stuff at infinity: this is the same procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86479/discussion-between-user1092847-and-denis-nardin).